# 2 divs on the same position with css and html:

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="about-me-photos blurry-photos photos">
    <div class="blurry-wrapper">
        <div class="blurry-inside blurry-front">
            <img class="about-me-img" src="imagefront.png">
        </div>
        <div class="blurry-inside blurry-back">
            <img class="about-me-img" src="imageback.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blurry-wrapper">
        <div class="blurry-inside blurry-back">
            <img class="about-me-img" src="back2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="blurry-inside blurry-front">
            <img class="about-me-img" src="front2.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need that blurry-front and blurry-back Have the same position inside blurry-wrapper.

I've tryed different combinations of float and clear, nothing works so far. What am I missing?

Comment: show us your css... are you positioning them using absolute position? floating and text-aligning is not for positioning purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` to the `blurry-back` class. This might do the trick.

Comment: You sent me in the right path!: this is what worked for me: .blurry-inside {
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
}

.blurry-wrapper{
 display:block;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
}

.blurry-back {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}